# Constantly check for keyboard input while theres already a loop

Tags: c

Im creating a little game thats like a keyboard version of guitar hero. I'm almost done, but i'm just confused over one thing. I want to constantly be checking if the player is pressing anything on the keyboard and to see if they are pressing the correct key, but I already have a loop that sleeps every 1 second to update the game, so I cant have another loop running at the same time to constantly check the keyboard input (or can I?). I tried putting the keyboard check inside the game loop, but since it sleeps every second, it sometimes doesnt catch when the player presses the key.
This is my while loop:

```
while (playing)
{
    updateBoard(score, game);
    checkKeyPress(game);
    Sleep(time);
    if (rand() % 2 == 1)
        spawnNewLetter(game);
}
```

updateBoard just prints out the new board, spawnNewLetter is just to spawn a new letter to fall down the board, and checkKeyPress is to check the keyboard input, this is it:

```
void checkKeyPress(char game[GAME_ROW][GAME_COL])
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case 97:
            checkLetter(game, 'a');
            break;
        case 98:
            checkLetter(game, 'b');
            break;
```

The function goes on, but its just repeating to check for all the letters.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your best solution is to use threads are you running on linux? Or windows as these vary from OS?

Comment: @Mr.Branch: `_khbit()` suggests windows